# Spawning words based on screen size

Tags: unity

I'm creating a typing game where the words fall from the top of the screen to the bottom. How do I set the words to spawn so that they adjust to the screen size of the device. This is the code that I have:

```
Vector3 randomPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-2.5f,2.5f), 7f);       
GameObject wordObj = Instantiate(PrefabWord, randomPosition, Quaternion.identity, Canvas);
```

But this doesn't scale properly with the size of the device.

**Edit:**

When I change the randomPosition to "new Vector3(Random.Range(0,Screen.width), 7f);", the words spawn all over the screen and not just within the bounds of the camera or canvas.

I have also switched the platform to android and selected 480x800 resolution. And in the old script where the random values were hardcoded from -2.5f to 2.5f, some of the words were getting clipped depending on the resolution selected.

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: What makes the current scaling behaviour "not proper"? What specifically needs to change to make it "proper"?

Comment: The x position is -2.5  and +2.5. But when I select the screen size as 480x800, some of the words are not shown in the screen. Is there any way to check the screen size and set the limits accordingly?

Comment: "Is there any way to check the screen size...?" [You checked the documentation, right?](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-width.html)

Comment: I used this code "new Vector3(Random.Range(0,screen.width), 7f);" But even now the words are way off screen..Not sure what the issue is..

Comment: Did that solve your problem? If so, add it as an Answer. If it didn't, update your Question to explain what went wrong.